# How to toggle a WPF Grid column visibility

Tags: wpf, binding, grid, gridsplitter, togglebutton

I'm having some trouble getting this to work in a WPF app I'm working on.  Basically, what I'm after is something like the Task pane in an MMC:

- The app has three columns in the main part of the display.  I need a column on the right side which is resizable.  I presume this means using a Grid with a GridSplitter but anything that works will do.
- I want to be able to save the width of the right-side column when the app is closed and load it when the app is opened but this should be an initial size: the user should be able to resize it.
- When I resize the window, I want the left- and right-side columns to stay the same size and the middle column to resize with the window width.
- The left- and right-side columns need to have a minimum width.  When I resize the right-side column I want the centre column to get smaller but not the left-side column.
- I also want to be able to toggle the visibility of the right-side column with a toggle button which is outside the column and when it returns to visibility I want it to be the same width it was before.

I'm trying to do as much as possible in XAML and with binding.

And can I have it topped with cream, ice cream and chocolate chips, please?  :-)

Comment: I've edited the original question quite heavily because my original was as clear as mud.

Comment: My second bounty in ten minutes.  Since I haven't had one completed yet, I'm not quite sure what happens.  I guess we'll see...

Comment: If you don't pick one the highest voted answer gets it automatically

Comment: With an automatic pick, the answerer only gets half the bounty, though. The automatic pick also only happens if the time on the bounty runs out and no answer has been chosen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As I read your requirements, instead of thinking of a `Grid`, I think of a `DockPanel`.

```
<DockPanel>
    <Grid Name="right"
        DockPanel.Dock="Right" MinWidth="100" />
    <Grid Name="Left"
        DockPanel.Dock="Left" MinWidth="100" />
    <Grid Name="middle" />
</DockPanel>
```

If you make a way to resize `right`, then `middle` will change as `right` is resized. If you resize the window, only `middle` will change. Storing and setting the `Width` of `right` is up to you, but shouldn't be hard.

As for allowing the user to resize `right`, that will a bit trickier, but I found [this article](http://www.windows-now.com/blogs/ndunlap/pages/2505.aspx) that should help. [This other article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DockPanelSplitter.aspx) might help even more.

For the visibility of `right`, you can set its `Visibility` to `Collapsed` to hide it and restore it by setting it to `Visible`.

Note: The panels inside don't have to be `Grid`s, but you will want to use some sort of `Panel` for each. Whatever you have inside your current `Grid` columns should work just fine.

Comment: I used your approach and the articles you suggested and it works like a charm.  I bind the Visibility properties of both the content and the splitter to the toggle button and all works as planned.  Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 8):

I used a Grid with GridSplitters since this made it really easy to resize the middle column while maintaining the widths of the left and right columns.

**XAML:**

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="MainWindow"
    Title="Main Window"
    Width="640" Height="480">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!-- Left column -->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200" MinWidth="100"/>
                <!-- Left GridSplitter column -->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                <!-- Center column. A width of * means the column will fill
                     any remaining space. -->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <!-- Right GridSplitter column -->
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="RightSplitterColumn" Width="5"/>
                <!-- Right column -->
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="RightColumn" Width="200"
                                  MinWidth="100"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                <Button x:Name="ToggleButton" Grid.Column="2"
                        Content="Toggle Right Column" Width="150" Height="25"
                        Click="ToggleButton_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code-Behind**

When hiding the right column, I just set the column width to 0 since grid columns don't have a visibility property.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private double rightColumnWidth;
    private double rightColumnMinWidth;
    private bool rightColumnHidden;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rightColumnHidden)
        {
            // Restore the widths.
            RightColumn.MinWidth = rightColumnMinWidth;
            RightColumn.Width = new GridLength(rightColumnWidth);
            RightSplitterColumn.Width = new GridLength(5);
        }
        else
        {
            // Remember the user-set widths for the columns.
            rightColumnWidth = RightColumn.Width.Value;
            rightColumnMinWidth = RightColumn.MinWidth;

            // Remember to set the minimum width to 0 before changing the actual
            // width.
            RightColumn.MinWidth = 0;
            RightColumn.Width = new GridLength(0);
            RightSplitterColumn.Width = new GridLength(0);
        }

        rightColumnHidden = !rightColumnHidden;
    }
}
```

As for saving and restoring the column widths on startup, I would just store the width variables to a settings file and then apply them when your app is reopened.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: it does achieve what I wanted so I've 'upped' it but I think this sort of thing is better done in XAML with binding wherever possible.  I've accepted Joel's answer because it's closer to that approach.  Thanks again for your work.

Answer (score 4):

Set the columndefinition Width to Auto and put a control inside that column and give Star for the other columns . Whenever you want to hide the column with content, set the control.Visibility=Collapsed and since column width is Auto, you wont see that column and the remaining columns will take the space.

Comment: I can't get this to work with the desired behaviour.  Setting Width to Auto means resizing the window affects the columns in what would appear to the user as non-sensical ways.

Answer (score 4):

3 years later you can find another approach on CodeProject.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437237/WPF-Grid-Column-and-Row-Hiding

It adds a "Visible" property to custom Column definitions.